# Subir un archivo a un servidor samba

Tags: java, samba

Estoy intentando subir un archivo a un servidor `samba` desde un servidor interno, pero no logro conectarme al servidor.
Mi proyecto corre en `192.168.1.199` y el servidor `samba` `192.168.15.99` este es el código.

Si puedo hacer ping entre los servidores:

```
private String sharedFolder = "smb://192.168.15.99/imagenes/Documentos/";

public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) throws MalformedURLException, SmbException, UnknownHostException, IOException {

     String user = "root";
     String pass = "Pass";

                    String path = sharedFolder + this.categoriaImagen + this.nuevaSolicitud.getIDENTIFICACION_DEUDOR() + secModifica + ".jpg";
                    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(null, user, pass);
                    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);        
                    SmbFileOutputStream out = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
                    InputStream orgFile=in; 
                     origenorgFile.copyTo(smbFile);
               int read = 0;
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                    while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                     out.write(bytes, 0, read);
                    }
                    in.close();
                    out.flush();
                    images.add(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(fileName))));
                    listaCategoriaIg.add(this.categoriaImagen);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();

                }
}
```

Este es el error:

```
10:16:40,055 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) jcifs.smb.SmbException: Failed to connect: 0.0.0.0<00>/192.168.15.99
10:16:40,056 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) jcifs.util.transport.TransportException
10:16:40,056 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: En tu código pone `192.168.12.99` pero indicas que es el `192.168.15.99`

Comment: es un error de edición, lo tengo como 15.99